# Portable Class Libraries are NOT automatically installed on Xamarin Studio Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, json.net, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

When i install Xamarin Studio on Mac, PCLs are not installed, though everyone says they are...

The following folder is empty. To my knowledge, this is where the PCL profiles should be :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/
```

How come Xamarin, or MDK, does not install these by default, as explained in [this post](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are installing the MRE and not the MDK like you thought you installed.